# onClick="history.go(0)" doesn't works in mozilla but works in IE. How to resolve this issue in mozilla browser

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I am using below line so that when i click a "New" button it will empty all the fields.
using onClick="history.go(0)" which works in IE but fails Mozilla.

```
  <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="New">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To empty all the fields, use reset button:

```
<button type="reset">New</button>
```

No need in JavaScript.